# Can i send parameter to php controller using javascript but without jquery or ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

well the question is enough explained can it be done.

what I am trying to do is to get data from a popup and onclose I want to send the content I retrieved to a php controller for processing.

But I dont want to use jquery library, because it is creating a conflict for me.

Update

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit()
{        

    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {           
        if(a[i].className == 'Ymacs-frame-content'){
            var b = a[i].getElementsByTagName("div").innerHTML;             
        //alert(b);
        }             
    }

//Ajax should be here

        window.onbeforeunload = reloadOpener;

        if (top.opener && !top.opener.closed) {
            try {
                opener.location.reload(1); 
            }
            catch(e) {  }
            window.close();
        }
    }
    window.ununload=function() {
        reloadOpener();


}
```

Comment: What sort of conflict? Why not fix conflict instead of avoiding using of jQuery?

Comment: why is using ajax a problem? You don't need jquery to use it!

Comment: You should illustrate the problem with some example code to get the desired answer.

Comment: You don't have to use jQuery for ajax... but you'll probably want to.

Comment: Use a common jQuery library, if it it creates conflict.

Comment: I added an update i dont know if it explain more ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use jquery-less AJAX:

```
var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
a.open("GET","myscript.php?var=foo&othervar=bar",true);
a.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( this.readyState == 4) {
        if( this.status == 200) {
            // data sent successfully
            // response is in this.responseText
        }
        else alert("HTTP error "+this.status);
    }
};
a.send();
```

Alternatively, you can create an `iframe` tag and point it to the right page. You can even create a form and post it to the frame if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in javascript without using jQuery since that is all jQuery does in the background.  You will need to look at the different ways IE does it compared to other browsers though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest), but you'll need to account for differences in browsers, which jQuery does for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this. The only way to use Javascript to pass info to PHP is by using XMLHttpRequest, or at least if there is another way I did not find it. It has to do with the fact that PHP renders on the server side, and Javascript isn't executed until after it is served to the client...unless you use the XHR which is...AJAX.